# Problems with Jinja2 and csrf token

Tags: django, csrf, jinja2

I've inherited a Django webapp that I need to add a basic file upload form to.  The app is using Jinja for it's template engine.  The first attempt of my upload template has a basic form like this:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<input type="file" name="datafile"></p>
<div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div></form>
```

I've added `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` to my MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES list and I'm using RequestContext in my upload view.

If I try to access my upload page I get this error in my app's debug ouput:

```
Encountered unknown tag 'csrf_token'. Jinja was looking for the following tags: 'endblock'. The innermost block that needs to be closed is 'block'.
```

After doing a little research I found the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7844539/how-to-csrf-token-protection-in-jinja2-template-engine) and changed my form to look like this

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}">
<input type="file" name="datafile"></p>
<div><input type="submit" value="Upload"></div></form>
```

However, that takes me back to the 403 Forbidden page with a `CSRF token missing or incorrect` in my debug output.

Any ideas what I need to do to get a csrf token playing nicely with jinja?

Comment: Have you checked that the generated html contains a csrf_token and that the <input> field looks correct?

Comment: Yeah, the token is getting generated and the input field looks normal.